# How to merge two condition in calculated column Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have one `calculated column` in which I had to put two condition.

1st Condition:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(FifteenDays)>=5,IF(WEEKDAY(FifteenDays)=7,FifteenDays+3,FifteenDays+4),IF(WEEKDAYFifteenDays)>1,FifteenDays+2,FifteenDays+2))
```

2nd Condition:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Go-LiveDeployment Date]),"",[Go-LiveDeployment Date]-30)
```

If I execute separately, this works. How to combine both these conditions into one formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your Formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(FifteenDays)>=5
    ,IF(WEEKDAY(FifteenDays)=7
        ,FifteenDays+3
        ,FifteenDays+4
       )
    ,IF(WEEKDAYFifteenDays)>1
        ,FifteenDays+2
        ,FifteenDays+2
       )
   )
```

There is a typo...

*at first glance* The logic can be replaced with:

```
=FifteenDays + CHOOSE( WEEKDAY(FifteenDays) , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 4 , 3 )
```

Your

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Go-LiveDeployment Date]),"",[Go-LiveDeployment Date]-30)
```

Is easier to read as:

```
=IF( [Go-LiveDeployment Date] , [Go-LiveDeployment Date]-30 , "" )
```

Because a date is a True value and an empty date is a False value

###Conditions

Combining conditions can be done in a 3rd column referencing these Calculated Columns or using the AND and OR **functions in SharePoint, not Operators**

```
=IF( AND( [First] , [Second] , [3rd] ) , "All true" , "one ore more False" )
```

###Calculated Column Functions Documentation:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List